# Как умножить значение счетчика Item на 10

Tags: zabbix

Добрый день. Как умножить значение счетчика Item на 10 ?
Есть счетчик на процессор **perf_counter[\238(_Total)\698]**
Мне нужно этот показатель умножить допустим на 10. Цель - Что бы на графике были другие значения.

Comment: мне важен синтаксис, потому что взять всё это допустим в скобки и умножить на 10 не работает  (...)*10

Answer (score 0):

В элементах есть вкладка **Предобработка**, возможность выбрать множитель, регулярное выражение и что угодно.